# showing odd numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have made this guessing numbers, if one writes any other number than between 10 and 20 it will show them accordingly, but I want that it shows odd numbers. 
 
For example, when I write 1, 2 ,3 and then 10, it will print 1, 2, 3 and 10, but I want it print every second number like this: 1, 3 and then 10 which is correct one.

 
I've tried many things, but couldn't make it work.

```js
var luku;
luku = Number(prompt("number"));

while (luku < 10 || luku > 20) {
  document.write(luku + "<br>");
  luku = Number(prompt("give number"));

}
document.write(" correct " + luku);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @walee do you mean odd numbers?

Comment: `i want it print every second number like this: 1, 3 and then 10 `  what this means? you don't want to print the second number?

Comment: @Nemanja Glumac no i mean just every other, i dont know in english, like if you write 6, 7, 9, 10, then it should print 6, 9 and 10

Comment: I'm sorry. You lost me. I have literary no idea what is the goal, nor what's the logic behind guessing numbers "game" or whatever this is.

Comment: if i write 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 what should you print?

Comment: @Vencovsky 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10

Comment: The logic is: as long as luku is not between 10 and 20, print every odd guess, so the first guess, the 3rd guess, the 5th guess. Once the guess is between 10 and 20, print the answer and stop. so 1,2,3,10 becomes 1,3,10 and 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 should  become 1,3,5,7,9,10, without a chance to enter 11. And 2,1,26,9,12 becomes 2,26,12

Comment: Nikhil Aggarwal seens to have the most correct answer

Comment: @Vencovsky why am i getting down voted ? i edited and corrected, english is not everybodys mother language.

Comment: @walee your question isn't clear, `every other number` doesn't make much sense, try translating `odd numbers` and `even numbers` to your mother language and than edit your question if this helps

Comment: @Vencovsky now better ?

Comment: @walee I have updated my answer, check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following using a `counter` variable which is incremented everytime in the loop and based on that (**odd values**) paints text.

```js
var luku;
var counter = 1;
luku = Number(prompt("number"));

while (luku < 10 || luku > 20) {
  // paint for odd values
  if(counter%2) document.write(luku + "<br>");
  counter++;
  luku = Number(prompt("give number"));
}
document.write(" correct " + luku);
```

Comment: We can't leave the alert until we finish the game. Please do not use of an alert

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT - That is a good suggestion but does it really draws a down-vote?

Comment: I got downvoted the other day because I correctly answered a poor question and the motivation of the downvoter was that answering poorly asked questions draws more bad questions. Maybe that happened here as well. +1 since I wrote the exact same code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check before appending the number to the document like:

```
if ((luku % 2) !== 0){
// Then add only
}
```

To display every second element from an array and exist integer:

```js
var luku;
var list = [];
luku = Number(prompt("number"));
var last;

while (luku < 10 || luku > 20) {
  last = luku;
  list.push(luku);
  luku = Number(prompt("give number"));
}
var listToDisplay = list.filter(a=>list.indexOf(a)%2===1)
listToDisplay.push(luku);
document.write(" correct " + listToDisplay);
```

To display Odd numbers from user input:

```js
var luku;
var list = [];
luku = Number(prompt("number"));

while (luku < 10 || luku > 20) {
  if ((luku % 2) !== 0){
  document.write(luku + "<br>");
  }
  luku = Number(prompt("give number"));

}
document.write(" correct " + luku);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a switch `odd` which flips every time a guess happens, so it only shows the odd ones.

```js
let guess
let odd = true
guess = Number(prompt('number'))

while (guess < 10 || guess > 20) {
  if (odd) document.write(guess + '<br>')
  odd = !odd
  guess = Number(prompt('Enter a number'))
}
document.write(' correct ' + guess)
```